# Regex string with optional suffix in Reqtify

Tags: regex

I try to filter the following lines in Reqtify:

```
Li.success tc_BT_Cancel_From_Pause_State_a4_2016-01-14_16h40m16s.log
Li.success tc_BT_Cancel_From_Pause_State_a5_2016-01-14_16h40m23s.log 
Li.success tc_BT_Cancel_Init_BtControlStop_2016-01-14_16h40m23s.log
```

With a first regex `^Li.\w+\stc_(\w+)_20` I achieve to extract

```
BT_Cancel_From_Pause_State_a4
BT_Cancel_From_Pause_State_a5
BT_Cancel_Init_BtControlStop
```

But my goal is to strip off the _a* suffix.

I already tried in an additional expression `(.+)(_a\d)?` but the result is unchanged.

Same for `(.+)(_a\d|)` .

Does anyone have an idea how to strip this optional part off?
The final list should be:

```
BT_Cancel_From_Pause_State
BT_Cancel_From_Pause_State
BT_Cancel_Init_BtControlStop
```

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
^Li.\w+\stc_(\w+?)(_a\d)?_20
```

Group 1 remains unchanged, group 2 will be the optional _aX.

If you don't want to group the second part, you can change it this way :

```
^Li.\w+\stc_(\w+?)(?:_a\d)?_20
```

Comment: This seems promising. I'll test it with my colleagues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this:

```
^Li.\w+\stc_(\w+?)(?:_a\d)?_20
```

With <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM4jT0/3)</kbd>